# C# Application to query both Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle

A few things about what I intend my .NET application to do:

1. Query various enterprise wide databases (I would not know the structure of these databases before hand, in terms of table or fields to expect)
2. These databases could either be Oracle or SQL Server
3. Have an interface where the user could select the table and the fields within, set group by and where clauses, to extract a recordset
4. Insert records into an Access database based on the results of the above query. I know the structure of this Access database and I have some business logic to execute before inserting the records in a certain way.

I am not sure if an ORM like NHibernate is really a solution to this requirement as I have no information before hand on the structure of data (tables, fields) that I will encounter. Is there a .NET library that will abstract the connection and querying part for me and one that works with SQL Server and Oracle.

Comment: How are you planning to handle datatype mapping?  If you have a set structure in Access, doesn't that imply that the query data has to conform to that?

Comment: Well may be you can use Enterprise library data access application block, If I were you I would have written my own abstraction on top of all three implementations, and write (or reuse) the concrete implementations of calling sps, storing records or retrieving as general implementations,